# Is there a way to automatically use FatRats in Raku?

Tags: raku

One of the neat things of Raku is that it automatically uses rational numbers instead of floating point numbers, when appropriate (e.g. when dividing two integers).
Unfortunately, once the denominator gets too large, floating point numbers are used anyway.

There is the `FatRat` type that doesn't do that, but as far as I can find, the only way to use those is to explicitly do so.

For instance, this script calculates digits of π:

```
#!/usr/bin/env raku

unit sub MAIN(Int $decimals = 1_000);

sub atan_repr(Int $n, Int :$decimals)
{
    my $x = $n;
    my $n2 = $n²;
    my $sign = 1;
    my $limit = 10**($decimals+2);
    my $result = FatRat.new(1, $x);
    for 3,5...* -> $i {
        $x ×= $n2;
        $sign ×= -1;
        $result += FatRat.new($sign, $i × $x);
        last if $x ≥ $limit;
    }

    return $result;
}

my $π = 4 × (4 × atan_repr(5, :$decimals) - atan_repr(239, :$decimals));
my $π-str = ~$π;      # Make sure we don't do string conversion over and over

print '3. ';
for 0,5...^$decimals -> $d {
    print "    # $d\n   " if $d && $d %% 50;
    print $π-str.substr(2+$d,5), ' ';
}
print "    # $decimals" if $decimals && $decimals %% 50;
say '';
```

It's pretty elegant, except for stuff like `FatRat.new(1, $x)`.  I'd much rather be able to use just `1/$x` and declare somehow that `FatRat`s should automatically be used instead of `Rat`s.  Perhaps something like `use bigrat`, similar to Perl's `use bigint` and `use bignum`?

Is there a way to do this that I haven't found?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `Rat`s by itself is fine, until you run out of precision (which is rare).  I think it was the 2022.02 release that introduced the `$*RAT-OVERFLOW` dynamic variable.  It specifies the behaviour that should be executed when a `Rat` overflows its precision.  By default, it is set to `Num`, meaning it will revert to using (lossy) floating point.

You can also set it to `FatRat`, which will cause automatic upgrade to `FatRat` as soon as a `Rat` runs out of precision.  You can also specify `Failure` (to have it `fail`), `Exception` (to have it throw an exception) or `CX::Warn` (to have it warn on downgrading to `Num`).

How does that work?  The `$*RAT-OVERFLOW` variable is supposed to be a class or instance, on which the `UPGRADE-RAT` method will be called when a `Rat` overflows.  So you *could* introduce your own behaviour by creating a class with an `UPGRADE-RAT` method in it.

So to activate this globally to upgrade to `FatRat`, you'd do:

```
INIT $*RAT-OVERFLOW = FatRat;
```

To activate this only for a lexical scope:

```
my $*RAT-OVERFLOW = FatRat;
```

I see this still needs to be documented :(

Comment: Thanks, @Elizabeth!  Simply adding `$*RAT-OVERFLOW = FatRat;` to the top of the script did the trick.  (Edit: didn't see your edit yet; `INIT $*RAT-OVERFLOW = FatRat;` is probably a bit safer.)

Comment: Recycled this answer to a doc entry: https://github.com/Raku/doc/commit/0a7a2e5215

Comment: Perhaps `$*RAT-OVERFLOW` should also be mentioned on https://docs.raku.org/type/Rat?  Somewhere around this sentence: “To prevent the numerator and denominator from becoming pathologically large, the denominator is limited to 64 bit storage. On overflow of the denominator a Num (floating-point number) is returned instead.”

Comment: See https://github.com/Raku/doc/commit/b95cdedbf8 .  mscha++

Comment: FWIW I like the default behaviour. As [this](https://lemire.me/blog/2020/03/15/number-of-atoms-in-the-universe-versus-floating-point-values) states: It is estimated that there are about ```10**80``` atoms in the universe. 

Yet the maximal value that we can represent using the common double-precision floating-point type is larger than ```10**308```. It is an unimaginably large number. 

If your software ever produces a number so large that it will not fit in a double-precision floating-point value, chances are good that you have a bug.

Comment: or you are calculating digits of π ;-)